# Add up values in list

Tags: r, list, merge

I'm currently working with a list which contains the following data:

```
>resultsList

$`1`
[1] "x" "0"           "1"           "1"           "1"           "5"          
$`2`
[1] "x /// y" "0"     "1"           "1"           "2"           "3"          
$`3`
[1] "x" "0"           "1"           "3"           "2"           "4"          
$`4`
[1] "x /// z" "0"     "1"           "2"           "2"           "2"          
$`5`
[1] "x" "0"           "1"           "3"           "3"           "4"          
$`6`
[1] "x" "0"           "0"           "0"           "1"           "2"          
$`7`
[1] "x" "0"           "2"           "2"           "1"           "4"               
$`8`
[1] "x /// y" "0"     "2"           "2"           "1"           "2"
```

I would like to add up all the numbers per column and only keep the value in column 1 which is present in every row.

The output should look like this:

```
>mergedData

[1] "x" "0" "9" "14" "13" "26"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Here is a solution that assumes that all your column 1 strings are in the form "var /// var2 /// ...". We first recover all unique variables like this:

```
resultsList <- list(c("x","0","1","1","1","5"), 
                    c("x /// y","0","1","1","2","3"),
                    c("x","0","1","3","2","4"),
                    c("x /// z","0","1","2","2","2"),
                    c("x","0","1","3","3","4"),
                    c("x","0","0","0","1","2"),
                    c("x","0","2","2","1","4"),
                    c("x /// y","0","2","2","1","2"))


firstColumn <- sapply(resultsList,"[[",1)
listsOfVariables <- c(strsplit(firstColumn," /// "))
vector <- c()
for(i in 1:length(listsOfVariables))
{
  vector <- c(vector,listsOfVariables[[i]])
}

uniqueVariables <- unique(vector)
uniqueVariables
[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Next, we find out which of these variables are contained in all of the individual rows:

```
matches <- sapply(1:length(uniqueVariables), function(x,y) grep(uniqueVariables[x],y), y=firstColumn)
variablesMatchingAllRows <- uniqueVariables[sapply(matches,"length")==length(resultsList)]
variablesMatchingAllRows
[1] "x"
```

We then paste the variables together (in case you have more than 1 variable that matches all rows):

```
variablesMatchingAllRowsTest <- c("x","y","z")
paste(variablesMatchingAllRowsTest,collapse=" /// ")
[1] "x /// y /// z"
```

We obtain the final column 1 string and add the column sums:

```
> finalString <- paste(variablesMatchingAllRows,collapse=" /// ")
> c(finalString,colSums("mode<-"(do.call(rbind, resultsList)[ , -1], "numeric")))
[1] "x"  "0"  "9"  "14" "13" "26"
```

**OLD ANSWER**

In the example below we will first find the unique string in column 1 that has minimal stringsize and then we will check if this minimal string is included in the other strings. We will then calculate the columnsums over the rows that were a match. We use this data for the example:

```
> resultsList <- list(c("x","0","1","1","1","5"), 
+                     c("a b x /// y","0","1","1","2","3"),
+                     c("x","0","1","3","2","4"),
+                     c("a /// z","0","1","3","3","4"),
+                     c("bd x","0","1","5","3","6"))
> resultsList
[[1]]
[1] "x" "0" "1" "1" "1" "5"

[[2]]
[1] "a b x /// y" "0"           "1"           "1"           "2"           "3"          

[[3]]
[1] "x" "0" "1" "3" "2" "4"

[[4]]
[1] "a /// z" "0"       "1"       "3"       "3"       "4"      

[[5]]
[1] "bd x" "0"    "1"    "5"    "3"    "6"
```

First, we find the `minimalString` and corresponding row indices that match this `minimalString`:

```
firstColumn <- sapply(resultsList,"[[",1)
minimalString <- unique(firstColumn[nchar(firstColumn)==min(nchar(firstColumn))])
indices <- grep(minimalString,firstColumn) # Grep on the first element in minimalString
```

We get:

```
> minimalString
[1] "x"
> indices
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

In other words, all rows except row 4 match your minimalString. Next we add all the columnsums over the matching rows like this:

```
> c(minimalString, as.character(apply(sapply(2:6,function(x,y,z) as.numeric(sapply(y,"[[",x)),y=resultsList)[indices,],2,sum)))
[1] "x"  "0"  "4"  "10" "8"  "18"
```

We will break it down further for clarity:

The inner `sapply(y,"[[",x))` will fetch all elements of index x in list y and will return them as a vector. We do this for `y = resultsList` and `x = 2:6`.
Note that we also have to convert the characters to numerics first:

```
> intermediateResult <- sapply(2:6,function(x,y,z) as.numeric(sapply(y,"[[",x)),y=resultsList)
> intermediateResult
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    1    1    5
[2,]    0    1    1    2    3
[3,]    0    1    3    2    4
[4,]    0    1    3    3    4
[5,]    0    1    5    3    6
```

Next, we calculate the columnsums of the rows that match the `indices`:

```
> sums <- apply(intermediateResult[indices,],2,sum)
> sums
[1]  0  4 10  8 18
```

Finally, we still have to convert the sums back to characters and add the unique column 1 identifier in front. We get:

```
> finalResult <- c(minimalString,as.character(sums))
> finalResult
[1] "x"  "0"  "4"  "10" "8"  "18"
```

**For your example** we get the following results:

```
> resultsList <- list(c("x","0","1","1","1","5"), 
+                     c("x /// y","0","1","1","2","3"),
+                     c("x","0","1","3","2","4"),
+                     c("x /// z","0","1","2","2","2"),
+                     c("x","0","1","3","3","4"),
+                     c("x","0","0","0","1","2"),
+                     c("x","0","2","2","1","4"),
+                     c("x // y","0","2","2","1","2"))
> firstColumn <- sapply(resultsList,"[[",1)
> minimalString <- unique(firstColumn[nchar(firstColumn)==min(nchar(firstColumn))])
> indices <- grep(minimalString,firstColumn) # Grep on the first element in minimalString
> minimalString
[1] "x"
> indices
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
> c(minimalString, as.character(apply(sapply(2:6,function(x,y,z) as.numeric(sapply(y,"[[",x)),y=resultsList)[indices,],2,sum)))
[1] "x"  "0"  "9"  "14" "13" "26"
```

Comment: Your edit is assuming correctly. Column 1 always contains string separated by '///'. While I like both answers, yours allows me to determine the variable which is always present in column 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
c(resultsList[[1]][1], 
  colSums("mode<-"(do.call(rbind, resultsList)[ , -1], "numeric")))
# "x"  "0"  "9"  "14" "13" "26"
```

---

Here, the function `"mode<-"` is used to change the mode of the matrix `do.call(rbind, resultsList)[ , -1]` including numbers represented as character strings.

The character matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, resultsList)[ , -1]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "0"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "5" 
# [2,] "0"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "3" 
# [3,] "0"  "1"  "3"  "2"  "4" 
# [4,] "0"  "1"  "2"  "2"  "2" 
# [5,] "0"  "1"  "3"  "3"  "4" 
# [6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "2" 
# [7,] "0"  "2"  "2"  "1"  "4" 
# [8,] "0"  "2"  "2"  "1"  "2"
```

The numeric matrix:

```
"mode<-"(do.call(rbind, resultsList)[ , -1], "numeric")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    1    1    1    5
# [2,]    0    1    1    2    3
# [3,]    0    1    3    2    4
# [4,]    0    1    2    2    2
# [5,]    0    1    3    3    4
# [6,]    0    0    0    1    2
# [7,]    0    2    2    1    4
# [8,]    0    2    2    1    2
```

The command `"mode<-"(x, y)` is similar to `mode(x) <- y` but does not change `x` and returns the result.

Comment: can you explain what "mode<-" does?

Comment: Another option is `c(resultsList[[1]][1],Reduce('+',lapply(resultsList, as.numeric))[-1])` non-numeric elements coerce to NA